# How to find multiple exact values on a particular field in elasticsearch query?

Tags: node.js, indexing, elasticsearch, exact-match, multiple-value

My Sample Data is shown below:

`{"listings":{"title" : "testing 1", "address" : { "line1" : "3rd cross", "line2" : "6th main", "line3" : "", "landmark" : "", "location" : "k r puram", "pincode" : "", "city" : "Bangalore" },"purpose":"rent","published": true, "inActive": false },
{"listings":{"title" : "testing 2", "address" : { "line1" : "3rd cross", "line2" : "6th main", "line3" : "", "landmark" : "", "location" : "banaswadi", "pincode" : "", "city" : "Bangalore" },"purpose":"sale","published": true, "inActive": false },
{"listings":{"title" : "testing 3", "address" : { "line1" : "3rd cross", "line2" : "6th main", "line3" : "", "landmark" : "", "location" : "tin factory", "pincode" : "", "city" : "Bangalore" },"purpose":"rent","published": true, "inActive": false }`

My index mapping is shown below:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/testing/listings/_mapping -d '{
 "listings" : {
    "properties" : {
        "address" : {
           "properties": {
              "location": { "type" : "string",
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
        },
        "suggest" : { 
             "type" : "completion", 
             "index_analyzer" : "simple",
             "search_analyzer" : "simple",
             "payloads" : true
        }                              
    }                                  
  }
}'
```

I access the listings object based on purpose property value like rent or sale.  I am able to access the objects for rent and sale individually.  How can i access listings object for both rent and sale values.  I have used below query to fetch both rent & sale listings object.

```
{"query":{
   "filtered": {
     "filter": {
       "terms": {
         "purpose" : ["rent", "sale"]
        }
      }
    },
   "bool":{
     "must":[
       {"match":{"published":true}},
       {"match":{"inActive":false}},
       {"match":{"address.city": "bangalore"}}
      ]
   }
 }
}
```

Please suggest the changes as needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try: `"execution" : "and"` ?

Comment: No i am new to elasticsearch so i dont know about that @Duc.Duong

Comment: `"terms": {
         "purpose" : ["rent", "sale"], "execution" : "and"
        }
      }`, it similar to ("rent" AND "sale"). Default is ("rent" OR "sale")

Comment: @Duc.Duong its giving 'SearchPhaseExecutionException' error

Comment: Here's the full body, please recheck: {"query":{
   "filtered": {
     "filter": {
       "terms": {
         "purpose" : ["rent", "sale"], "execution" : "and"
        }
      }
    },
   "bool":{
     "must":[
       {"match":{"published":true}},
       {"match":{"inActive":false}},
       {"match":{"address.city": "bangalore"}}
      ]
   }
 }
}

Comment: @Duc.Duong same error is coming i updated my question with my index can you look and tell me any changes required in the index mapping..

Comment: There're many errors in the query you provided. I'll explain it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

There're a couple of things:

1. `address` should be declared as `nested object` to prevent wrong search results in the future when searching address fields. You can refer here for more info about problems with `inner object`, `nested object` : http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/
2. When use `nested object`, the mapping will look like this (address type : nested):

   `"listings" : {
   "properties" : {
       "address" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties": {
             "location": { 
                 "type" : "string",
                 "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
       },
       "suggest" : { 
            "type" : "completion", 
            "index_analyzer" : "simple",
            "search_analyzer" : "simple",
            "payloads" : true
       }
   }
   }`
3. And the query will change a bit: use `terms` with `execution=and`, and use `nested query` for address fields:

`"query":{
   "filtered": {
     "filter": {
       "terms": {
         "execution" : "and",
         "purpose" : ["rent", "sale"]
        }
      },
    "query" : {
       "bool":{
         "must":[
           {"term":{"published":true}},
           {"term":{"inActive":false}},
           { "nested": {
              "path": "address", 
              "query":
                 {"match":{"address.city": "bangalore"}}
            }
           }
          ]
       }
    }
 }
}`

You should refer the elasticsearch documents for syntax of each kind of query.
Hope it help

Comment: if my sample data is contains another property called "residentialKind":"Row House" or "residentialKind":"Individual House" or "residentialKind":"Apartment" or "residentialKind":"Villa" then how should i modify my mapping? I tried by adding as "index":"not_analyzed" but its giving the correct output. If I query as "residentialKind": ["Aprtment","Row House"] then the "hits" giving as 0. If query like "residentialKind": ["aprtment","Row House"]  or "residentialKind": ["aprtment","row house"] then "hits" giving me the results only for "apartment" kind listings. Plz help me:-)

Comment: what kind of query you used ? terms ?

Comment: can you post the full query ?